# C# sends Spam when POST data is used

Tags: c#, post

So this is really weird, maybe someone can point me in the right direction.

Here's my controller code:

```
MailMessage message = new MailMessage("foo@MySite.com", "bar@MySite.com");
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(Request["action"].ToString());
message.Subject = Request["action"].ToString();
MySite.Models.Mail.SendMail(message);
```

The weird part is if I hard code the subject to "contact" I get an email normally, however if I use Request["action"] I get a Spam message.

Edit: Reworded the question because I actually was receiving the message, but it was going to my Spam inbox instead of the non-spam inbox.

Comment: what happens if you store the `action` attribute in a string before assigning it to `message.Subject`?

Comment: `but the email does not send`, then what happens? exception? unexpected *subject* ?

Comment: Check the return value of `Request["action"]`.

Comment: Actually turns out that when I use the Request, the spam filter thinks its Spam. wtf?

Comment: does `Request["action"].ToString() == "contact"` return true?

Comment: @mrtig Yes, System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(Request["action"].ToString() == "contact");, displays True

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It was the content I was sending. This is not a C# issue, it is the Spam filter. Apparently "contact" as a subject is grounds for Spam.